# Python Tkinter - TextBox1 Not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, nameerror

I am learning somethings about Python Tkinter, and I wrote this simple code:

```
from Tkinter import * 
import tkMessageBox


def print_it(msg):
    Text1.insert(INSERT, str(msg))

top = Tk()




Entry1 = Entry(width=300)
Entry1.pack(side='top')
Button1 = Button(text='Send',width=300,command=print_it("Message"))
Button1.pack(side='top')

Text1 = Text(height=600,width=300)
Text1.pack(side='top')



top.geometry('640x480+10+10')
top.title('GUI')
top.mainloop()
```

I don't know why, but it is giving me the error:

> NameError: global name 'Text1' is not defined

If I replace the `Text1` in the print_it def with  `Entry1` , it won't give me any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `print_it` instead of using a reference to the function as the value of the `command` parameter.

Replace following line:

```
Button1 = Button(text='Send',width=300,command=print_it("Message"))
```

with

```
Button1 = Button(text='Send',width=300,command=lambda: print_it("Message"))
```

Comment: Oh thanks, but that wasn't the problem. I needed to declare the Text1 widget before declaring the Button1 widget.

Comment: @JohnBlack, If you don't replace `command=` part, button click will not trigger `print_it` function call.

Comment: Yes, but the main problem was that. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @JohnBlack: no, the main problem is definitely _not_ that you need to declare Text1 before the button. You only need to do that because you are using the `command` parameter wrong. If you use it properly, it doesn't matter when you define Text1 (other than it needs to be defined before someone clicks on the button)